# Regarding checking of an condition

Tags: java

```
  public static final int FALSE = 0;
  public static final int TRUE = 10;
```

Please advise me for one thing I have this below piece of code below

```
     if (!walgreensRewardsSupport.isPreProdOrTrainingMode()
        && walgreensRewardsSupport.isWagRewardsRedeemptionEnabled()
        && null != walgreensRewardsInfoLine
        && null != walgreensRewardsInfoLine.getMemberFullProfile()
        && (null != walgreensRewardsInfoLine.getMemberFullProfile().getRewardPoints())
        && (walgreensRewardsInfoLine.getMemberFullProfile().getRewardPoints().getCurrentBalance() != 0)
        && !transaction
            .getBooleanValue(ITransactionHashtableWag.REWARDS_REDEMPTION_ZIPCODE_LIMIT_REACHED)
        && !walgreensRewardsRedemptionSupport.isLoyaltyRedemptionTenderLineExist(transaction)
        // No need to force recalculation each time, recalculation happens after any tender line is
        // added to transaction.
        && walgreensRewardsRedemptionSupport.getRedemptionEligibleTransactionAmount(transaction,
            true, false).isGreaterThanZero()) {
      return TRUE;
    }   
else {
      return FALSE;
    }

  }
```

Now I have to add an condition in between it ...Check if
walgreensRewardsInfoLine.getMemberFullProfile().getRewardPoints().getValues().size()
is 0 then do return False..I have done in the following way..

```
     if (!walgreensRewardsSupport.isPreProdOrTrainingMode()
        && walgreensRewardsSupport.isWagRewardsRedeemptionEnabled()
        && null != walgreensRewardsInfoLine
        && null != walgreensRewardsInfoLine.getMemberFullProfile()
        && (null != walgreensRewardsInfoLine.getMemberFullProfile().getRewardPoints())
        && (walgreensRewardsInfoLine.getMemberFullProfile().getRewardPoints().getCurrentBalance() != 0)
        && !transaction
            .getBooleanValue(ITransactionHashtableWag.REWARDS_REDEMPTION_ZIPCODE_LIMIT_REACHED)
        && !walgreensRewardsRedemptionSupport.isLoyaltyRedemptionTenderLineExist(transaction)
        // No need to force recalculation each time, recalculation happens after any tender line is
        // added to transaction.
        && walgreensRewardsRedemptionSupport.getRedemptionEligibleTransactionAmount(transaction,
            true, false).isGreaterThanZero()) {
      return TRUE;
    }else if (walgreensRewardsInfoLine.getMemberFullProfile().getRewardPoints().getCurrentBalance() == 0)
{
return FALSE
}   
else {
      return FALSE;
    }

  }
```

Please advise is it correct..!!

Comment: 1. You can't expect an answer less than 120 seconds after posting your question. 2. Have you tested that it works as expected? If not, what unexpected behaviour have you noticed?

Comment: What are TRUE and FALSE? If they're just true and false, why aren't you using the normal Java literals? Between that and the "null != ..." this looks more like C than Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate users: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1370546/user1370546 and http://stackoverflow.com/users/1188021/neera

Comment: I am not surprised you are confused about this, the check is horribly complex. A series of smaller checks that each return TRUE and/or FALSE (or better, `true`/`false`) would make the intent clearer. Whether you are correct or not totally depends on the desired business logic and nobody here can answer that.

Comment: Possibly related :-) http://www.walgreens.com/topic/walgreens-rewards/rewards.jsp

Answer (score 2):

In the first code block, you have:

```
if (condition) {
  return TRUE;
} else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

This can be simplified to:

```
return (condition) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

And if TRUE and FALSE are just booleans,

```
return (condition);
```

In the second code block, you have:

```
if (condition1) {
  return TRUE;
} else if (condition2) {
  return FALSE;
} else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

The else-if has no value unless you expect side effects from the evaluation of the second condition.

Also note that some thoughtful use of private methods can make this code much easier to understand. You can encapsulate a part of your big condition like this:

```
private boolean hasRewardsPointsBalance(InfoLine infoLine) {
  if (null == infoLine) return false;
  MemberProfile profile = infoLine.getMemberFullProfile();
  if (null == profile) return false;
  RewardsPoints rewards = profile..getRewardPoints();
  if (null == rewards) return false;
  return (rewards.getCurrentBalance() != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to just add the logical complement of what you want for false to the set of conditions that are being logically and'ed together to return true.

For example:

```
 if (!walgreensRewardsSupport.isPreProdOrTrainingMode()

    && walgreensRewardsInfoLine.getMemberFullProfile().getRewardPoints()
       .getValues().size() != 0

    && walgreensRewardsSupport.isWagRewardsRedeemptionEnabled()
    && null != walgreensRewardsInfoLine
    && null != walgreensRewardsInfoLine.getMemberFullProfile()
    && (null != walgreensRewardsInfoLine.getMemberFullProfile().getRewardPoints())
    && (walgreensRewardsInfoLine.getMemberFullProfile().getRewardPoints().getCurrentBalance() != 0)
    && !transaction
        .getBooleanValue(ITransactionHashtableWag.REWARDS_REDEMPTION_ZIPCODE_LIMIT_REACHED)
    && !walgreensRewardsRedemptionSupport.isLoyaltyRedemptionTenderLineExist(transaction)
    // No need to force recalculation each time, recalculation happens after any tender line is
    // added to transaction.
    && walgreensRewardsRedemptionSupport.getRedemptionEligibleTransactionAmount(transaction,
        true, false).isGreaterThanZero()) {

  return TRUE;
```

This is less complex than what you coded.